# How to test localized prices with In-app billing v3

Tags: android, in-app-billing

My app displays prices as reported by the getSkuDetails() API. To confirm that it is working I'd like to setup my device to display prices for different locales.

I've tried logging in with Google accounts from different countries and setting the system language but prices still appear in my own locale.  How can I setup my device so that I can see prices reported in different locales?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess that's not easy. In my case I experienced the same issue. According to some information I read, it looks there are several procedures Google uses to locate the user. One of them consist of to check the procedence of the Credit Card registered in Google Play, if users has any one. So if that is your case, you will be always shown with the prices of the locale corresponding to your credit card.

Second check, is made thru Sim card of the mobile phone. If you don't have Sim card or device is a tablet without Sim card, then the next step is looking to the WiFi connection.

Localization of the WiFi spot, and IPAddress, is used also to geolocate the user.

Finally if nothing of this works, then locale settings in the device is used. So in this way, Google show the prices according to the place where you are, which couldn't match with your locale settings in your device.

For example, if you're spanish, with your tablet with local settings in Spanish, and you're right now in USA, it has sense to show you the prices in Euros, because that will be the price charged in your credit card, and you will understand better the currency conversion, because you use euro in your life.

I hope this helps you.

So as a resume, how to test it? Very difficult.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I was hoping that I had just missed something and there was an easy way to test the formatted prices. Apparently not. Hopefully Google adds something to address this as some point.

Answer (score -1):

From the DOCS of the In-App Purchase API v3

> The API also introduces a long-anticipated feature: the ability to query in-app product information directly from Google Play. Developers can now programmatically obtain an item's title, description and price. No currency conversion or formatting is necessary: prices are reported in the user's currency and formatted according to their locale

Answer (score -1):

When you add Product on Google Play they also provide option for supporting price for different locales. Global Currency is USD and price is converted according to local currency automatically.