# Android testing different currency prices

Tags: android, google-play, android-billing

I have been trying to find an answer to this for a while now, but all the result are at least 5-6 years old, with no satisfactory answer.

`How to test local prices?` All I want to, is to be able to see the SKUs in different currencies, for each country the app is supported in.
I can't believe that in the current time there is no way to manually change your `Play Store` region without having a valid payment method for that region, or using a VPN (at least based on the top [search result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108519/how-to-test-localized-prices-with-in-app-billing-v3) on how the currency is selected)

iOS has a `sandbox` account that you can manually change the country and with that the currency it will show, is there nothing like that for Android?

I use a test account, so I have the `test cards`, but I don't see any way to change the country/currency for it.

I really hope that I'm just missing something obvious, and there is a way to test this.

Comment: It seems it's not so easy. I've found this article https://www.alphr.com/change-currency-google-play/, which describes how to change currencies in Google Play, maybe it will help. But, in my opinion, the general idea that you should just setup currencies in Google Play Store and rely on Google that the correct currency will be displayed in  your app according to the user's location and payment method. If you worry about that just recheck twice the currencies on Google Play to make sure they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

To change the currency, follow these steps:

1. Access the Google Play Store app.
2. Choose the “Menu” icon.
3. In the dropdown, choose “Account.”
4. Find your country and name underneath the “Country and profiles.”
5. If you don’t already have a payment method for the new country, you will have to add it first.
   The first payment method has to be from the country you are creating a profile for.
   The Google Play Store will automatically change to the new country. This can take up to 48 hours to apply, but it’s also possible for the change to happen sooner.

If you don’t have a payment method for the new country, here’s how to add it:

1. Access the Google Play Store app.
2. Choose the “Menu” icon.
3. From the dropdown, select the “Payment methods” page.
4. Under the “Add payment method” section, select the one you would like to add.
5. Input the card number, the “valid thru” date, and the card verification code (CVC).
6. Edit the cardholder name, or address information if needed.
7. Select “Save” and the new payment method will be saved to your Google account.

Comment: While I do appreciate the try, that's exactly what the first google result tells you and it doesn't help since you need a valid payment method for that country.